# "Never ask again" feature on Electron dialog.showMessageBox method

Tags: javascript, checkbox, callback, dialog, electron

I have a dialog.showMessageBox that works well and do what I tell it to do.

```
electron.dialog.showMessageBox({
            type: 'info',
            buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
            message: 'Are you sure?',
        }, resp => {
            if (resp === 0) {
                // User selected 'Yes'
                foo.bar();
            }
        });
```

But it's annoying to answer each times this function is called, I'd like to insert a "Never ask me again" like this.

```
electron.dialog.showMessageBox({
            type: 'info',
            buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
            message: 'Are you sure?',
            checkboxLabel: 'Never ask me again',
            checkboxChecked: false
        }, resp => {
            if (resp === 0) {
                // User selected 'Yes'
                foo.bar();
            }
        });
```

[image: Dialog box]

The documentation says that the boolean `checkboxChecked` can be used in the callback function but I'd like to know how to make it global so that the question isn't ask anymore.

Comment: You could save it into a var and check if it is true anytime you want to display that message.

Comment: Isn't that a problem since the app's purpose is to be closed an re-opened all the time?

Comment: If you want to save it not only for one session, you could write/create a configuration file for your app, since this is the easiest and most user-friendly way because your users could then simply re-enable the messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here's what I've done:

```
const settings = require('electron-settings');

settings.set('neverAskMeAgain', {
    state: false
});

        if (!settings.get('neverAskMeAgain.state')) {
            electron.dialog.showMessageBox({
                type: 'info',
                buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
                message: 'Are you sure?',
                checkboxLabel: 'Never ask me again',
                checkboxChecked: false
            }, (resp, checkboxChecked) => {
                if (resp === 0) {
                    foo.bar();
                    settings.set('neverAskMeAgain.state', checkboxChecked);
                }
            });
        } else if (settings.get('neverAskMeAgain.state')) {
            foo.bar();
        }
    } else {
        foo.bar();
    }
```

It works like a charm within an instance of the app when running `npm install && npm start` but when I quit it and relaunch it, the dialog box is displayed again...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a lib named `electron-settings`. [Link here.](https://github.com/nathanbuchar/electron-settings)
That way, your code would look something like that:

```
const settings = require('electron-settings'); 
electron.dialog.showMessageBox({
    type: 'info',
    buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
    message: 'Are you sure?',
    checkboxLabel: 'Never ask me again',
    checkboxChecked: false
    }, 
    resp => {
        if (resp === 0) {
            // User selected 'Yes'
            settings.set('never_ask_again_answer', true); 
            foo.bar();
        }
    });

    // get the answer later
    let answer = settings.get('never_ask_again_answer')
```

EDIT: I think it doesn't work when you restart because you're just setting it to false again right at the start. Little fix will do:

```
const settings = require('electron-settings');

if(!settings.has('neverAskMeAgain')){ // this if might do it
    settings.set('neverAskMeAgain', {
        state: false
    });
}

if (!settings.get('neverAskMeAgain.state')) {
    electron.dialog.showMessageBox({
        type: 'info',
        buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
        message: 'Are you sure?',
        checkboxLabel: 'Never ask me again',
        checkboxChecked: false
    }, (resp, checkboxChecked) => {
        if (resp === 0) {
            foo.bar();
            settings.set('neverAskMeAgain.state', checkboxChecked);
        }
    });
} else if (settings.get('neverAskMeAgain.state')) {
    foo.bar();
}
```